# How to use recursion to reverse a String?

Tags: java, string, recursion, char, substring

```
    public String reverse(String word) {

    if ((word == null) || (word.length() <= 1)) {
        return word;
    }
    return reverse(word.substring(1)) + word.charAt(0);
}
```

I have this code that professor sent me but I don't get it. I know what recursion is but I'm still a newbie at Java Programming so if anybody would care to explain to me the part 
return reverse(word.substring(1)) + word.charAt(0);

what does the subString(1) does and the chartAt(0)?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 1):

The way the recursive part of this works is that to reverse a string, you remove the first character, reverse what's left, and then append the first character to the result. That's what the prof's code is doing.

- `word.substring(1)` returns the substring starting at index 1 and going to the end
- `word.charAt(0)` returns the character at index 0

There's a bit more going on when the two pieces are appended using `+`. The issue is that `word.charAt(0)` has a return type of `char`. Since the left-hand part of the `+` is a `String`, the [Java language rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) say that the right-hand side must be converted to a `String` if it isn't one. So the `char` value is first converted to a `Character` and then the `toString()` method of the `Character` class is called. This returns a `String` consisting of the single character.

It might have been more efficient code to write that line like:

```
return reverse(word.substring(1)) + word.substring(0, 1);
```

The two-argument version of `substring` returns the substring between the two indexes. That would eliminate the [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and conversion to `String`.

Answer (score 1):

This is [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29). Here are documentation for [subString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) and [charAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).
Coming to how this works:

```
public static String reverse(String word) {

    if ((word == null) || (word.length() <= 1)) {
        return word;
    }
    return reverse(word.substring(1)) + word.charAt(0);
}
```

**Pass1:** reverse("user") : `return reverse("ser")+'u';`

**Pass2:** reverse("ser")+'u' : `return reverse("er")+'s'+'u';`

**Pass3:** reverse("er")+'s'+'u' : `return reverse("r")+'e'+'s'+'u';`

**Pass4:** reverse("r")+'e'+'s'+'u' : `return 'r'+'e'+'s'+'u';` // because here `"r".length()==1`

Answer (score 1):

```
return reverse(word.substring(1)) + word.charAt(0);
```

you should read it this way:

- remove the first letter away from the `word`
- reverse the rest (recursive call)
- put the first letter at the end

if you assume this function reverses the strings of length N, you can easily see that it must reverse the strings of length N+1. If you realize that the word with at most one letter is the same if reversed (the first three lines of code), you have a complete very simple proof using [Mathematical Induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) that this function really reverses the string.